# cloud run - error while connecting to cloud sql

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I am trying to connect to **cloud sql** from **cloud run**. However, I am getting the error, not sure what needs to be done.

**Code**

```
def create_database_connection(db_user, db_pass, db_name, instance_connection_name):

    db_socket_dir = os.environ.get("DB_SOCKET_DIR", "/cloudsql")
     pool = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
 
        sqlalchemy.engine.url.URL.create(
            drivername="mysql+pymysql",
            username=db_user,  # e.g. "my-database-user"
            password=db_pass,  # e.g. "my-database-password"
            database=db_name,  # e.g. "my-database-name"
            query={
                "unix_socket": "{}/{}".format(
                    db_socket_dir,  # e.g. "/cloudsql"
                    instance_connection_name)  # i.e "<PROJECT-NAME>:<INSTANCE-REGION>:<INSTANCE-NAME>"
            }
        ),
    )

    return pool


@app.route('/test', methods=['GET'])
def handle_test():
    connection = database.create_database_connection(db_user=os.getenv("db_user"), 
                                                     db_pass=os.getenv("db_pass"),
                                                     db_name=os.getenv("db_name"),
                                                     instance_connection_name=os.getenv("instance_connection_name"))

    Session = sessionmaker(bind=connection)
    session = Session()
    records = session.query(Demo).all()
    records_list = [record.__dict__ for record in records]
    for record in records_list:
        del record["_sa_instance_state"]

    print(records_list)
    json_string = json.dumps(records_list)
    return json_string
```

**Error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 602, in connect sock.connect(self.unix_socket) FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

in connect raise exc sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) 
(2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' ([Errno 2] No such file or directory)")
```

I am using **gcloud run** to deploy the app directly from source code. So image is being build and deployed by google cloud build.

I tried creating folder as well, in docker file however still getting same error.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.10-slim

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED True

ENV APP_HOME /app
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
COPY . ./

RUN mkdir -p /cloudsql

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

CMD exec gunicorn --bind :$PORT --workers 1 --threads 8 --timeout 0 main:app
```

**Update:**

- I can see folder `/cloudsql` being created
- I changed the `DB_SOCKER_DIR` to `/tmp` and still the same issue.

I have no issue connecting to same database with same code through `cloud function`. I am getting error only with `cloud run`

I am using following command to `deploy cloud run`

```
gcloud run deploy processcontrol --source .  --set-cloudsql-instances=cloud-sql-8
```

I have connection set for the SQL I am trying to access.

[image]

Comment: How are you deploying this app? Do you use some Dockerfile, or its done via GCP console?

Comment: @dannyxn I have updated the question.

Comment: Were you trying to run it locally? Check this [article](https://medium.com/@williamwxz/google-cloud-cant-connect-to-mysql-server-on-localhost-65e7f8bd2d4d).

Comment: What's the MySQL version? Is your database publicly accessible? (public IP?)

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere yes, database is publically available. I am able to connect it from my laptop without any issue.

Comment: @MabelA.  I am not running this locally. I am running from `cloud run` only.

Comment: Ok, And what's the MySQL version?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere my sql version is `MySQL 5.7` same code, same sql I am able to connect with `cloud function`. However, due to few reasons I am trying to explore `cloud run`

Comment: From my latest tests, only MySQL 8 worked. I didn't find any reference of that in the documentation. I don't know if it's still the case, but if you can have a try with a Cloud SQL MySQL 8, it could be great.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I tried with `my sql 8` and I am still getting the same error. seems like I am missing some important point.  I have now added both the databases in connection

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere how does it understands which `host` to connect ? I am using `init_unix_connection_engine` method to connect.

Comment: What are your requirements?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere i want to connect cloud-sql from cloud run. I am following the official document and still getting error.

Comment: What is the deploy command? Did you add the command line option **--set-cloudsql-instances=CLOUDSQL-INSTANCE**? https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/run/deploy#--set-cloudsql-instances Unless you declare the SQL Instance when deploying, your connection will fail.

Comment: @JohnHanley yes it's in place. I have shared the screenshot.

Comment: Your latest update showing a screenshot does not answer my comment. Show the CLI command **gcloud deploy ...**. If you are not using the CLI do a test using the CLI and post the results.

Comment: @JohnHanley i shared the command line code I am using

Answer (score -1):

Are you enabling the Cloud SQL Proxy in the Cloud Run instance?
More info on setting that up here:

https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-run

Comment: yes it's enabled.